# redirect stdin from file descriptor in linux c

Tags: c, linux, file, dup

I can't understand what's wrong with the following code. I perform exactly the same actions twice. It works for the first time, and fails for the second.

1. open FD
2. duplicate to stdin.
3. close stdin
4. close the original fd

At the second time I get an error, at stage 4, which means the FD is already closed.

```
  int fd =open("/path/to/some/file",0,"r");
  if (dup2(fd,STDIN_FILENO)<0)
    perror("dup_in");
  if (close(STDIN_FILENO)<0)
    perror("close_in");
  if (close(fd)<0)
    perror("close_fd");

  //Up to here it works fine.

  fd =open("/path/to/some/file",0,"r");
  if (dup2(fd,STDIN_FILENO)<0)
    perror("dup_in2");
  if (close(STDIN_FILENO)<0)
    perror("close_in2");
  if (close(fd)<0) //<-- ERROR!
    perror("close_fd2"); //<--close_fd2: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: The [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) call closes the current destination file descriptor, so when you close `STDIN_FILENO` you close the duplicate you just made.

Comment: Whether `fd ` is opened in the first instance?. Check for the value

Comment: Possibly related to your problem, you *really* need to read [the `open` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), because you're not using it correctly. In fact the compiler should complain about those calls, and if not then add the flag `-Wall` to enable more warnings.

Comment: Joachim - dup2 duplicate the fd to a new fd. Meaning I have to close original and the new one when I finish. What is wrong with this use of open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2)

> `int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);`
>
> If `oldfd` is a valid file descriptor, and `newfd` has the same value as oldfd, then `dup2()` does nothing, and returns `newfd`.

So, in your second case, `open()` uses the least available FD, `0` [free'd by last call to `close()`]. That's how `oldFD` and `newFD` becomes the same, creating the error.

Note: Before using the `fd` returned by `open()`, you should always verify the sucess of `open()` call.

Comment: Thank You! My original problem was with FD created by socket accept call. For which I don't see in the man page that is uses the lowest available FD (but after checking it is the same problem).